# How to place a placeholder for date and time in html?

Tags: html, css, date, placeholder

I am working on html email in which I want to place a placeholder for dynamic contents. The snippets of code from html email where I have used dynamic contents are:

```
<tr>
   <td>
      <table cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" border="0" width="100%" style="color:#484848;font-family:'Champagne & Limousines';font-size:20px;padding-left:5%;">
         <tr>
            <td style="padding-bottom: 3%;text-align:right;">type:</td>
            <td style="padding-bottom: 3%;padding-left: 8%;">{{availability_check_request}}</td>
         </tr>
         <tr>
            <td style="padding-bottom: 3%;text-align:right;">estimated total:</td>
            <td style="padding-bottom: 3%;padding-left: 8%;">{{estimated_total}}</td>
         </tr>
         <tr>
            <td style="padding-bottom: 3%;text-align:right;">what</td>
            <td style="padding-bottom: 3%;padding-left: 8%;">{{what}}</td>
         </tr>
         <tr>
            <td style="padding-bottom: 3%;text-align:right;">how many</td>
            <td style="padding-bottom: 3%;padding-left: 8%;">{{how_many}}</td>
         </tr>
         <tr>
            <td style="padding-bottom: 3%;text-align:right;">when:</td>
            <td style="padding-bottom: 3%;padding-left: 8%;">{{when}}</td>
         </tr>
         <tr>
            <td style="padding-bottom: 3%;text-align:right;">who:</td>
            <td style="padding-bottom: 3%;padding-left: 8%;color:#FF8D58;">{{who}}</td>
         </tr>
      </table>
   </td>
</tr>
```

**Problem Statement:**

I am wondering what placeholders I would be using for:

**March 28/18 @ 7:00pm to March 30/18 @ 7:00pm**

At this moment, in the code above I have used {{when}}. Is it should be `{{$date_from}}` to `{{$date_to}}` ?

Comment: What template system are you using? Also what lang is this?

Comment: Laravel Blade which is itself a template and we are using php to dynamically pass the data.

Comment: @DevanshJ I have used html in the code above and it will be integrated with php.

Comment: @DevanshJ Does it answer your question ?

Comment: So is when a php variable? It seems not because it doesn't start with $ sign. What is "when" here? also you need two pieces of data "from" and "to", here it's only one

Comment: @DevanshJ The above html code will be integrated with php. When includes `From(example May25th 7pm)` and `To(example May28th 7pm)`. In the above code, I have mentioned like that. I am not sure whether it is right or wrong. Problem statement best explain my question.

Comment: I doubt the information your are providing is too less for me to solve it

Comment: If the question is specific to Laravel Blade, you should add that tag to it. Also, have you tried `{{$date_from}} to {{$date_to}}`? It sounds like either that would work, or it wouldn't work, and both results would answer your question! In other words, show us what you tried.

Comment: I have tried {{$date_from}} to {{$date_to}] but I am not sure whether it is right or not ?

Comment: You should also remove the css tag